# Rails 4 - how to get user name from their id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a order show page shown below. I had this working but ever since I changed computers to work on this app, the name did not display.

If I change `<%= @order.user.name %>` to `<%= @order.user.id %>`, I get the correct id. Otherwise I get nothing displaying where as the name of the id should be posted.

#### #view/orders/show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Code:</strong>
  <%= @order.code %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Client:</strong>
  <%= @order.client.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @order.user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Notes:</strong>
  <%= @order.memo %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Status:</strong>
  <%= @order.status ? "Confirmed" : "In Progress"  %>
</p>



<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(@order) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', orders_path %>
```

#### #models/order.rb snippet

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

#### #model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :telephones, dependent: :destroy

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    enum role: [:user, :manager, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end
end
```

#### #controllers/order_controller.rb snippet

```
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    @order.status = TRUE

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you have the correct associations in the models of user and order.like `has_many :orders`, `belongs_to :user` also check that the user actually has a name which i suspect. Go to your consel and print out the user and verify he has a name.

Comment: silly me the name field for the user is blank. thanks @Acacia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I just answered another question of yours, but I would recommend using the [`.delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method like this:

```
#app/models/order.rb
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true #-> @order.user_name
end
```

You can delegate multiple variables if you need to.
This fixes [Law of Dementer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), as described [here](http://pivotallabs.com/rails-delegates-are-even-more-useful-than-i-knew/)

Answer (score 2):

It's completely independent of the machine you use, so there have to be some changes you've made in your code that you don't remember.

Check what value is returned when you call this user from the console. Type `rails c` in the terminal and then type a command:

```
User.find(<<ID_OF_USER_WHOES_NAME_IS_NOT_DISPLAYED>>).name
```

If its name is empty, it could be a problem with creating a user or something.

Make update when you'll check it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, the value for the user name is empty and that is why it displays a blank when looking for the name.

Adding a name(string) to the user.name will solve the issue

When using a different database, make sure to also update the database with data, preferably the same data which initially tested with.